# ScrollViewer not working inside DockPanel

Tags: wpf

I have the fallowing code example, which behavior is shown on image below.

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False" >
    <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <ItemsControl>
            <Label Content ="First" BorderBrush="Violet" BorderThickness="2"/>
            <Label Content ="Second" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2"/>
            <Label Content ="Third" BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="2" />
            <Label Content ="Fourth" BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="2"/>
            <Label Content ="Fifth" BorderBrush="Maroon" BorderThickness="2"/>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Button Height="50" DockPanel.Dock="Top">button</Button>
</DockPanel>
```

[image]

The problem here is that Button is getting clipped during resize and only then ScrollViewer activates. How can I prevent Button clipping and resize ScrollViewer instead when there is not enough space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exchange the order of the DockPanel children and set `LastChildFill` to `True` to make the ScrollViewer filling. Dock the Button at `Bottom` and set the Dockpanel's `VerticalAlignment` to `Top`.

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Button Height="50" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">button</Button>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ItemsControl>
            <Label Content ="First" BorderBrush="Violet" BorderThickness="2"/>
            <Label Content ="Second" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2"/>
            <Label Content ="Third" BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="2"/>
            <Label Content ="Fourth" BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="2"/>
            <Label Content ="Fifth" BorderBrush="Maroon" BorderThickness="2"/>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```